# aws CLI install window

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, aws-cli

I am having trouble installing the aws CLI for windows.

I am following these instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-windows.html#awscli-install-windows-pip)

It requires that I have Python 3.6.2 but I have Python 2.7.6 when I run  python --version

After I run

```
 pip install --user --upgrade awscli
```

and then try to run

```
aws --version
```

nothing happens.

I tried setting my path in Environment Variables but it still won't work. 
After this, I tried to upgrade my python version by installing python 3.6 on their website, but my python version won't update when I run python --version.

Could this be that start of why I cant install the CLI?

Comment: Usually when you install python 3 it's available via `python3` instead of `python`.

Comment: Python3 get configured with python3 env variable when installed with existing python 2.7 installation. Try python3 --version and see what happens. Similarly pip3 for pip. Now you can use them to install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this link to download and install AWSCLI [Download the AWS CLI MSI installer for Windows](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-windows.html#install-msi-on-windows)

then go to C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI or where-so-ever you have installed this and set the path in Environment variables.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through the steps on the amazon website? Python 2 and 3 are quite different from what I understand.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html

The AWS script you are running is really just a python program. I recommend verifying install paths, and possibly use their bundled installer found on the page above, about half way down.

Answer (score 0):

At first make sure you have installed python3. Check it with command:

Try to verify python version with command(on centos or redhat):

```
$ rpm -qa|grep python3
```

And then make sure python3 has been added to $PATH

```
$python3 --version
```

And I think you need to install pip3 for python3.X.

```
$yum search python3|grep pip
```

And then install the package you need with command

```
$ pip3 install --user --upgrade awscli
```

Answer (score 0):

You can develop Python software for AWS in both Python 2.x and 3.x. The CLI is written in Python 2.x.

You can have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed on your system. You can either specify the python.exe manually using its full path (not recommended but I do this all the time) or by updating your environment PATH variable to point to the correct Python installation. I use a batch file so that I can switch back and forth between Python 2 and Python 3.

When you run "pip install --user --upgrade awscli" the version of Python that is running determines the awscli package that is downloaded and installed.

For Microsoft Windows, AWS provides an MSI installer package that contains everything that you need including the correct version of Python 2.7. I recommend that you start with the AWS Windows MSI and then learn how Python works (environment) on Windows.

Keep in mind that Python 2.x is going away. This is not official but plan for January 1, 2020 as the drop dead day. This means where possible develop for Python 3. IMHO it is time to stop developing for AWS in Python 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

If you have choco installed the following will work....

```
choco install -y awscli
$env:Path += ';C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI'
```